# "Smart" switch keeps disconnecting from wi-fi network

Tags: networking, wifi, linux

I bought a smart switch to control my room lamp. It is a JWCOM Smart SA-01 model with very little to no documentation available on the internet (at least I wasn't able to find anything useful). The problem is that whenever I connect the device on the wi-fi network it either disconnects and keeps trying to reconnect or it kicks my phone from the network. Since the only two devices connected to my wi-fi network are my phone and this switch, I think that it might be consuming too much band and the router has no other option to kick one of them off of it.

I contacted the seller about this issue and they didn't give a valid answer, saying that the problem might be occurring due to the wi-fi signal being too weak, which is not the case because the switch is literally less than a meter from the router.

Since I don't know the problem, do you guys know a Linux command that allows me to check for the band usage on my wi-fi router? Has anyone run into a similar problem before and, if so, what did you do to fix it? Since my router doesn't provide band control by MAC address, is there a way to control the network usage of this device from my computer somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is very strange that it can kick your phone from the network. I would try the following:
1. Update the router to the latest firmware. 2. Try setting a fixed IP addr for the smart switch in the wifi router. 3. Try moving the switch to be about 3 meters away from the router.

Comment: the wifi router may have a logging feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a got it to work was to buy a separate router and connect only the switches to it. Sometimes one of them still keeps disconnecting but it is better than having my phone kicked from the network all the time.